# Vegan fish fillet or vegetarian fish?

Tags: word-usage, nouns, idiomatic-language

We normally say "vegan fish fillet" shown in the image below.  [Here is the product](http://vegetarian-plus.com/product/vegan-fish-fillets/)

List of ingredients:

> Water, Soybean Fiber, (soybean protein, wheat starch, wheat protein, soybean oil), Soybean Protein, Soybean Oil, Tapioca Starch, Spice,Raw Cane Sugar, Sea Salt, White Pepper Powder, Laver, Yeast Peptone Powder, Natural Vegan Flavor.

Can we instead say "**vegetarian fish**" to describe this food?

[image]

Comment: If the dish really is made from fish, I don't think many vegans/vegetarians would accept the usage (it would be a *vegan/vegetarian fish **substitute***). Note that many people distinguish between vegan/vegetarian on the basis that the latter is a broader term which may include people who eat foodstuffs containing (or created using) dairy produce and/or eggs. Vegans usually adopt a stricter position (*in extremis*, they might even avoid food produced by people who wear leather shoes to work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sounds fine to me. The word `vegetarian` plays the role of an adjective and it combines with `fish` to create a compound noun. The noun implies the fish is for vegans or made by/belongs to a vegan.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* say "vegetarian fish" but it would be an [*oxymoron*](http://www.fun-with-words.com/oxym_example.html).  As FumbleFingers points out in his comment, most would say "fish *substitute*" or some other phrase to make it clear no *actual* fish were harmed in its production, for example:

> [Caroline's Vegetarian **Fishless** Tuna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OUY7G54)

but then there's this:

> [Harmony Valley **Vegetarian Hamburger** Mix](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00474H936)

More often you find this kind of compromise:

> [Gardein, Mandarin Orange Crispy **Chick'n**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LXZU03S)

It's not chicken, it's *chick'n* (chicken substitute actually made from soy, wheat, etc.)

The ultimate answer is, vendors will call their product whatever they think vegetarians and vegans will *buy*.  So, yes, "vegetarian fish" would be perfectly OK -- **if** vegans and vegetarians are OK with it.